# data transformation from one form of array to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have doubt about data structure transformation from one form of array to another.

My input data is of the form,

```
var testVar=[

{
    "count": 1,
    "term": "Company",
    "Company": [
        {
            "Tata": [
                {
                    "count": 1,
                    "term": "Tatagroup"
                }
            ],
            "sector": "Automotive",
            "type": "Car"
        },
      ]
},
{
    "count": 2,
    "term": "Country",
    "Country": [
        {
            "France": [
                {
                    "count": 1,
                    "term": "France"
                }
            ],
            "region": "Europe",
            "Player": "Zidane",
            "term": "France",
            "code": "FRA"
        },
        {
            "region": "Europe",
            "Player": "Federer",
            "term": "Switzerland",
            "Switzerland": [
                {
                    "count": 1,
                    "term": "Switzerland"
                }
            ],
            "code": "SWI"
        }
    ]
}];
```

and I am trying to transform it to the form,

```
[ "Tata" : [{"sector" : "automotive"}, "type" : "car"], "France": [{"region" : "Europe}, {"Player" : "Zidane"} , {"code" : "FRA"}], "switzerland" : [{"region" : "Europe}, {"Player" : "Federer"} , {"code" : "SWI"}]];
```

The code I came up with looks like http://jsfiddle.net/X2apw/2/, bt its nt accurate..

Comment: Your desired result is not JSON

Comment: First: It's broken -- `["Tata":[]]` will give you an error. `{ "Tata" : [] }` is acceptable. As is `[{"Tata":[]}]`.  What you've got right now is a whole lot of broken JSON.  Same goes for the `["type":"car"]`. Again, `{"type":"car"}` or `[{"type":"car"}]`.  Second...  ...why would you want to do this?  Even if you got it right, why would you want to select objects like `parsedData[0].Tata[1].type;  parsedData[1].France[0].region; parsedData[1].France[1].Player; parsedData[2].switzerland[2].code;`?  Where's the benefit in not knowing which term is in which object at which point in which array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var testvar = [...];

var result = {};
for (var i=0; i<testvar.length; i++) {
    var arr = testvar[i][testvar[i].term];
    for (var j=0; j<arr.length; j++) {
        var resarr = [];
        for (var k in arr[j]) {
            if (typeof arr[j][k] == "string") {
                 var obj = {};
                 obj[k] = arr[j][k];
                 resarr.push(obj);
            } else {
                 result[k] = resarr;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

([Demo at jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/X2apw/3/))

However, I strongly recommend to use just one object instead of an array of one-property-objects in your result format. Change the inner loop body to:

```
        var resobj = {};
        for (var k in arr[j]) {
            if (typeof arr[j][k] == "string") {
                 resobj[k] = arr[j][k];
            } else {
                 result[k] = resobj;
            }
        }
```

([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/X2apw/4/))

Comment: thanks ...I am trying to get the data in to this format as I need all the details related to switzerland when I give the input switzerland, the key field may vary for different entites and I am trying to access this realtime